# Matlab: Can I lock the Y axis (Even when the Zoom In/Out is used)?

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I have a plot and I want the user to not be able to change the Y axis. Is it possible?

Is there a call back option to the Zoom In/Out tool function?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution:

```
ZoomHandle = zoom(h.Figure(1))
set(ZoomHandle,'Motion','horizontal')
```

Thanks to all that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the help files for "zoom".

Generically, to set the zoom to horizontal only for the current figure all you need is:

```
set(zoom(gcf),'Motion','horizontal','Enable','on');
```

Comment: This did not work (or I used it wrong).

1st - the Zoom 'FigureHandle' is not the figure I want to control
2nd - the Y axis still changed when I used the Zoom tool

Comment: I noticed that under the tab of 'Tools' there is an 'Options' item.

There I can select that the Zoom will be a 'Horizontal Zoom'.

Is it possible to have that by default when the Plot is opened?

Answer (score 0):

This can be adjusted via the handle graphics behaviour property, see [this article on undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/handle-graphics-behavior/).

Comment: I tried several options there but none of them helped - The Zoom In option in the 'Tools' tab still changed the Y and the X axes